# How can I make this whitespace into a new path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

I remember drawing this tea bag with the pen tool. I then made some coloured rectangles around it, played around with the shape builder tool (if I recall correctly) to get the coloured shapes to stick around the tea bag. Then I accidentally removed the tea bag, and now I would really like to know how to easily re-create the tea bag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `Shape Builder` tool. Select all of the paths that make up the outline of your shape, then hover over the center of the negative space. The tool will highlight the area in a gridded pattern. Clicking will create a new shape.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Put a black square under all of it, then Select All and <kbd>Pathfinder > Divide</kbd>. Your shape will be in the results.

Comment: `Pathfinder > Merge` would also work and not split top objects.